# Error in python multi-socket communication through ansible

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ansible

I wrote a code to pass the parameter value from the master node to the slave by using one master and 6 as slaves through a total of 7 GCP instances, receive data from the slave as an argument value, and pass it back to the master.

However, when dealing with 5 servers, there was no error, but as soon as the 6th server is reached, the raddr of the 6th server changes and socket communication does not proceed. what's the reason?

Code running on the master server

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from socket import *
from select import *
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":

    """
    CLIENT
    """
    HOST = ["ansible2", "ansible3","ansible4","ansible5","ansible6","ansible7"]
    PORT = 8080

    DATASET = [
        "2021-11-01 00:00:00,2021-11-01 01:00:00",
        "2021-11-02 00:00:00,2021-11-02 01:00:00",
        "2021-11-03 00:00:00,2021-11-03 01:00:00",
        "2021-11-04 00:00:00,2021-11-04 01:00:00",
        "2021-11-05 00:00:00,2021-11-05 01:00:00",
        "2021-11-06 00:00:00,2021-11-06 01:00:00",
    ]

    JOB_NUM = len(HOST)

    for i in range(JOB_NUM):
        ADDR = (HOST[i], PORT)
        print("ADDR : ", ADDR)

        clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        print("client socket create")

        try:

            clientSocket.connect(ADDR)
            clientSocket.send(DATASET[i].encode())

        except Exception as e:
            print("%s:%s" % ADDR)
            clientSocket.close()

        print("%s:%s send success" % ADDR)
        clientSocket.close()
    print("send successed")

    """
    SERVER
    """
    print("receiving data")
    HOST = "0.0.0.0"
    PORT = 8080
    BUFSIZE = 1024
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
    print("ADDR2 : ",ADDR)


    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    print("socket create")

    serverSocket.bind(ADDR)

    serverSocket.listen(10000)
    print("socket listen")

    recv_msg = []

    for i in range(JOB_NUM):
        print("JOB_NUM : ",i)

        clientSocket, addr_info = serverSocket.accept()

        print("socket accept")
        print("--client information--")
        print("addr_info : ",addr_info)

        print(clientSocket)


        data = clientSocket.recv(65535).decode("utf-8")
        recv_msg.append(str(data).split(","))
        print("received data :", data)


        clientSocket.close()

    serverSocket.close()
    print("serversocket closed")
    print("receive successed\n")

    """
    PROCESS
    """
    s_time = time.time()
    res = 0
    data_len = 0
    for i in range(JOB_NUM):

        res += float(recv_msg[i][0]) * int(recv_msg[i][1])
        data_len += int(recv_msg[i][1])
    aggregate_time = time.time() - s_time

    data_scale = 0
    proc_time = 0
    for i in range(JOB_NUM):

        data_scale += int(recv_msg[i][2])

        proc_time += float(recv_msg[i][3])
    proc_time = proc_time / JOB_NUM

    avg = res / data_len

    print("avg:", avg)
    print("data_len:", data_len)
    print("data_scale:", data_scale)
    print("proc_time:", proc_time, "sec")
```

code running on slave server

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from socket import *
from select import *
import sys
from time import ctime
import psycopg2
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import time


def cal_sum(input_list):
    res = 0
    for i in input_list:
        res += i

    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":

    """
    SERVER

    """
    HOST = "0.0.0.0"
    PORT = 8080
    BUFSIZE = 1024
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    print("socket create")


    serverSocket.bind(ADDR)
    print("socket bind")


    serverSocket.listen(1000)
    print("socket listen")


    clientSocket, addr_info = serverSocket.accept()
    print("socket accept")
    print("--client information--")
    print(clientSocket)


    data = clientSocket.recv(65535).decode("utf-8")
    print("receive data :", data)


    clientSocket.close()
    serverSocket.close()
    print("close")

    """
    PROCESS
    """

    q_date = str(data).split(",")


    CONNECTION = (
        "postgres://userid:password@ip:port/dbname"
    )
    conn = psycopg2.connect(CONNECTION)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    sql = (
        "SELECT * FROM rack "
        "WHERE \"TIMESTAMP\" > '{}' and \"TIMESTAMP\" < '{}'".format(
            q_date[0], q_date[1]
        )
    )
    df_rack = psql.read_sql(sql, conn)

    df_rack.to_csv("./test.csv")

    dict_rack = df_rack.to_dict()

    print("DataSize(len):", len(df_rack))
    print("DataSize(len)", sys.getsizeof(df_rack))

    s_time = time.time()
    target_col = "RACK_VOLTAGE"
    #target_col = "BANK_SOC"
    res = 0
    for val in dict_rack[target_col].values():
        res += val
    avg = res / len(dict_rack[target_col])
    print("avg:", avg)
    e_time = time.time() - s_time
    print("proc_time:", e_time)


    send_data = (
        str(avg)
        + ","
        + str(len(df_rack))
        + ","
        + str(sys.getsizeof(df_rack))
        + ","
        + str(e_time)
    )
    print("send_data:", send_data)

    """
    CLIENT
    """

    HOST = "ansible1"
    PORT = 8080
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)


    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    print("client socket create")

    try:

        clientSocket.connect(ADDR)
        print("connection try")
        clientSocket.send(send_data.encode())
        print("send try")

    except Exception as e:
        print("%s:%s" % ADDR)
        sys.exit()

    print("connection is success")
    sys.exit()
```

Error from master server: 6th server changed ip

```
ADDR :  ('ansible2', 8080)
client socket create
ansible2:8080 send success
ADDR :  ('ansible3', 8080)
client socket create
ansible3:8080 send success
ADDR :  ('ansible4', 8080)
client socket create
ansible4:8080 send success
ADDR :  ('ansible5', 8080)
client socket create
ansible5:8080 send success
ADDR :  ('ansible6', 8080)
client socket create
ansible6:8080
ansible6:8080 send success
ADDR :  ('ansible7', 8080)
client socket create
ansible7:8080 send success
send successed
receiving data
ADDR2 :  ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
socket create
socket bind
socket listen
JOB_NUM :  0
socket accept
--client information--
addr_info :  ('10.178.15.6', 33890)
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.178.15.2', 8080), raddr=('10.178.15.6', 33890)>
received data : 689.639341300656,28784,11053200,0.0025081634521484375
JOB_NUM :  1
socket accept
--client information--
addr_info :  ('10.178.15.5', 47652)
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.178.15.2', 8080), raddr=('10.178.15.5', 47652)>
received data : 683.6560173610022,28800,11059344,0.0025205612182617188
JOB_NUM :  2
socket accept
--client information--
addr_info :  ('10.178.15.4', 40660)
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.178.15.2', 8080), raddr=('10.178.15.4', 40660)>
received data : 684.7850403002041,28784,11053200,0.002741575241088867
JOB_NUM :  3
socket accept
--client information--
addr_info :  ('10.178.15.3', 44272)
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.178.15.2', 8080), raddr=('10.178.15.3', 44272)>
received data : 685.5479756944368,28800,11059344,0.0025811195373535156
JOB_NUM :  4
socket accept
--client information--
addr_info :  ('10.178.15.8', 47018)
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.178.15.2', 8080), raddr=('10.178.15.8', 47018)>
received data : 685.3038402780469,28800,11059344,0.002821683883666992
JOB_NUM :  5
socket accept
--client information--
addr_info :  ('147.182.255.64', 57536)
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.178.15.2', 8080), raddr=('147.182.255.64', 57536)>
received data : GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1
Host:
Connection: close
User_Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36



serversocket closed
receive successed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_simple.py", line 118, in <module>
    res += float(recv_msg[i][0]) * int(recv_msg[i][1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1\nHost: \nConnection: close\nUser_Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML'
```

Up to 5 is no problem. I wonder if there is a limit for socket communication. please tell me the answer

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a socket communication issue. Ansible was the problem. Ansible's default fork value was 5. So, I changed it to 10 through the options and ran it. `ansible-playbook -f 10`